# How to add "rotate video" items to context (right-click) menu in Nemo

Tags: shell-script, video, nemo

I want to add 3 right-click items to the Nemo context menu to rotate a video file clockwise, anticlockwise, or 180°. This is useful when going through video collections that might not have rotation metadata.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is for Nemo in Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, but it should be useful in other instances as well. It consists of two files, a `.nemo_action` file and a `.sh` script, for each rotation, plus an icon for each.

Make sure ffmpeg is installed (`sudo apt install ffmpeg`).

**Installer**

For the quick and easy way, download the following folder, unzip it, use a terminal to navigate to it, set all files to executable, and run `./rotatevideos.sh`. This will install all scripts and icons as described below.

Please read the instructions, especially the **Notes** section, before installing.

[Installer (Dropbox folder)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zdusi1y4187nrll/AADW1r_zWjN2xNqMQHF99QwEa?dl=0)

**Scripts**

Place a file named `rotate90clockwise.nemo_action` in `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/`:

```
[Nemo Action]

Name=Rotate 90° clockwise
Comment=Rotate video 90° clockwise
Exec=<rotate90clockwise.sh %F>
Icon-Name=rotate90clockwise
Selection=s
Extensions=mp4;mpeg4;mkv;avi;mov;qt;wmv;m4v;mpg;mp2;mpeg;mpe;mpv;m2v;
Quote=double
Terminal=true
```

Then, in the same folder, add a file named `rotate90clockwise.sh`:

```
ffmpeg -i "$@" -vf "transpose=1" -acodec copy -y uD29Ajdsi419z.mp4
rm %F
mv uD29Ajdsi419z.mp4 "$@"
```

Repeat the process for anticlockwise and 180° rotations, changing the filenames as appropriate.

For anticlockwise, change `"transpose=1"` in the `.sh` file to `"transpose=2"`.

For 180°, change `"transpose=1"` in the `.sh` file to `"transpose=1,transpose=1"`. There doesn't seem to be a way to directly rotate 180°, so this rotates 90° twice.

**Icons**

Place icons for each of the three actions into `~/.local/share/icons/`. Make sure they are named as defined in `Icon-Name=` in the `.nemo_action` file.

Clockwise icon

[image: Clockwise icon]

Anticlockwise icon

[image: Anticlockwise icon]

180° icon

[image: 180° icon]

**Notes**

The script writes a rotated copy called `uD29Ajdsi419z.mp4`, erases the original, and then replaces the original with the rotated copy. I found that I needed an extension, but the fact that it's `.mp4` is irrelevant; the original file extension is restored when rotation is completed. The arbitrary filename is intended to be unlikely to clash with anything else you may have.

Note that this overwrites the original file. Make sure you have a backup, or change the `.sh` file to not overwrite (delete lines 2 and 3).

**Reasons for `.nemo_action` options:**

`Selection=s` shows the menu item only when a single video is selected. Rotating multiple videos at once would need different code.

`Extensions` includes all the extensions I expect to use; add some if you need to.

`Quote=double` is needed to allow the script to work on filenames with spaces etc.

`Terminal=true` runs the process in a terminal window which closes upon completion. Rotating large videos can take some time, so this gives you a visual indication of when the process is finished.